# SQL Replace a minus number with brackets

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a column of financial data that shows. Some figures are positive and some are negative.

Is it possible to change a number like -945 to (945) this is on SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Column data type?

Comment: @jarlh I am unable to change the structure so need to do this in the SQL query.

Comment: I just wanted to know the column data type... Is it integer, char etc...

Comment: But what type is the data in the source column? It'll change what you need to do depending on if its a string or integer.

Comment: @SeanR it is an integer

Comment: SQL Server is not doing this, the application you use to view your resultset (SSMS presumably) does this. So use one that allows you to format your data however you desire. If you do this in the query, then you must change the datatype to string. Doing that will have consequences for whoever uses this information. Are you certain this is a path you want to take?

Answer (score 1):

The following expression should work for most cases:

```
SELECT num, CASE
    WHEN num < 0 THEN '(' + CAST(-num AS VARCHAR(11)) + ')'
    ELSE CAST(num AS VARCHAR(11))
END AS frmtd
FROM (
    SELECT    0 AS num UNION ALL
    SELECT  945        UNION ALL
    SELECT -945
) tests
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an SQL function called `ABS()` that basically changes negative and positive numbers to just their relative value from 0, meaning it removes the minus but doesn't affect positive values.

You can find out more about it [here](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/arithmetic-functions/abs.php)

Comment: And how does this help? Seems more like a comment.

Comment: As far as I understand his question, he asked for a way to get rid of the leading zero in an integer. This function does exactly that in the shortest way possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `Replace` function in Sql Server as shown below.

When value is in (-) ve.

```
Select CAST(REPLACE(CAST(-945 as Varchar(4)), '-', '') as Int)
```

When value is already in (+) ve.

```
Select CAST(REPLACE(CAST(945 as Varchar(4)), '-', '') as Int)
```

The output in both case will be: `945`